# SVN access issue

Tags: svn

I am having some difficulty accessing my svn repository. Cannot browse the repository, do updates and/or commits, basically nothing can be done. I get "can't open file /format permission denied" error.

Other users are able to perform all operations normally. Is there a way some logging can be enabled to figure out what exactly has gone wrong? I use svn+ssh//servername/reponame/

SVN is running on Solaris.

Any quick verifications that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Your user needs read & write access to the repository path on the server.  Usually this is accomplished by adding all developers to a group and then changing the ownership of the repository (and all sub directories) to that group.  The permissions will also have to be set to something like 770 using chmod.

For more details look at the [svn+ssh section of the redbean book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch06s03.html#svn-ch-6-sect-3.4)